# Python swapping lists

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking, python-internals

In python, when I assign a list to another, like:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
```

Now b and a point to the same list. Now considering two lists,

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
a,b = b,a
```

Now how is it that they are swapped like any other data type and does not end up both pointing to the same list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like Python internally swaps the items. Check this program

```
a, b = [1, 2], [2, 3]

def func():
    a, b = b, a

import dis
dis.dis(func)
```

**Output**

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
              6 ROT_TWO             
              7 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (b)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, Python pushes **references** from `b` and `a` in the stack with [`LOAD_FAST`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST). So, now the top most element is the reference pointed by `a` and the next one is the reference pointed by `b`. Then it uses [`ROT_TWO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) to swap the top two elements of the stack. So, now, the top most element is the reference pointed by `b` and the next one is the reference pointed by `a` and then assigns the top two elements of the stack to `a` and `b` respectively with [`STORE_FAST`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST).

That's how sorting is happening in the assignment statement, when the number of items we deal with is lesser than 4.

**If the number of items is greater than or equal to four**, it builds a tuple and unpacks the values. Check this program

```
a, b, c, d = [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6]

def func():
    a, b, c, d  = d, c, b, a

import dis
dis.dis(func)
```

**Output**

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
              9 LOAD_FAST                3 (a)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             15 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (a)
             21 STORE_FAST               2 (b)
             24 STORE_FAST               1 (c)
             27 STORE_FAST               0 (d)
             30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's why I had to make `references` in bold.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got you :) Please check my updated answer, including the tuple unpacking stuff.

Comment: As for the optimisation I talked about; it is indeed limited to two and three item unpacks; see [`peephole.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/31fd129960d5/Python/peephole.c#l426) if you are interested. For two items, `BUILD_TUPLE` and `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` is replaced by `ROT_TWO`, for three items it is replaced by `ROT_THREE` then `ROT_TWO`. Because 4 items would require *three* opcodes (`ROT_FOUR`, then `ROT_THREE` then `ROT_TWO`) it is no longer worth optimizing for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good that you read this. :) Otherwise this answer would have been misleading. Updated that sentence. Please check now

Answer (score 2):

Because Python assignment *first* evaluates the right-hand-side expression, *then* applies the result to the left-hand-side targets.

So, *first*, Python creates `(<reference to list b>, <reference to list a>)` as a tuple, *then* assigns the first item in that tuple to `a`, and the second item in that tuple to `b`. This swaps the references around neatly.

You could expand the assignment to read it like this:

```
tmp = b, a
a = tmp[0]
b = tmp[1]
```

Comment: Looks like Python doesn't create a tuple here. Please check my answer.

Comment: No, because the assignment is optimised.

Comment: That comment went out a little too early (on my mobile). The assignment is optimised; the compiler skips creating a tuple when multiple assignment is used. There is no point. But for *understanding what happens* imagining it is a tuple is fine. In the expanded assignment example `tmp` *is* a tuple.

Comment: Yup. That was my initial understanding. Even my first edit had that tuple based answer only. I simply tried `dis` and got surprised. :)

Comment: I think it's pretty much optional whether you think of the LHS of the assignment as being a tuple, or as being a grammar production consisting of a comma-separated list of entities (which themselves may be such lists). Of course it's both, but in general when a comma-separated list of sub-expressions is evaluated for its result a tuple is created. When that same grammar production (called `testlist` in the formal Python grammar) is assigned to, one isn't.

Comment: @SteveJessop: the compiler produces a `BUILD_TUPLE` opcode in both cases, but the peephole optimizer then replaces that opcode with `ROT_` opcodes when there is an assignment on the LHS and only 3 or 2 values are involved. For more elements, tuples are still actually created.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ah, thanks. I didn't realise this was a special case. @Aswin: I think it's also instructive to work through why `a[:], b[:] = b, a` doesn't swap the contents of the lists -- once  it's obvious to you why not, and also obvious why `a, b = b, a` does swap the references, then you probably understand how the unpacking and assignment works :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Now how is it that they are swapped like any other data type and does not end up both pointing to the same list?

Because the moment you **unpack** the tuple `b, a` into the tuple `a, b` you loose references to the original `a` and `b` and they get re-assigned.