# python generators/ variable

Tags: python, generator, variable-assignment

2 questions...

1) I am trying to wrap my brain around this...
I am to understand that variables can take values using such code syntax as this:

```
a ,b = 2, 3
```

and that this would be the same as coding:

```
a = 2
b = 3
```

I hope this is correct.

So here is my puzzlement. I have the following code using a generator:

```
def fibonacci_generator() :

    a = b = 1

    while True :

           yield a

           a , b = b , a + b


fib = fibonacci_generator()

for i in fib :

       if i > 100 :

        break

       else : 

        print ('Generated: ', i)

print (next(fib))
```

(yes this is code from a python learning book)

If I were to rewrite this code and instead assign my a and b variables like so:

```
yield a

a = b

b = a + b
```

then I get different returns for a.
I am not understanding why this is??? Super frustrated about it!

2) When I run the code as written the first time above, I get the number 233 printed at the end. I also cannot figure out why??!!

Comment: This is definitely not the exact code from a python learning book. Your indentation is off (I'm sure it is otherwise the same code from that book) ;]

Comment: @aIKid Agreed. Voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

`a` is set to `b`, and `b` is set to `a+b`.

In this code:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

`a` is set to `b`, and `b` is afterwards set to `a+b`. But since `a` is already set to `b`, then `b` is in fact set to `b+b`.

Comment: This has the clearest explanation.

Comment: Geeze, Thank you so much! Spent 2 days trying to just logically sit and figure out what was going on. Got it now. You are the man!

Answer (score 1):

```
a , b = b , a + b
```

is not the same as

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

Because, when you say

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

It will first prepare the values on the right side `b, a + b` and assign them to the variables on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Python computes the right hand side *first* and then assigns the value (or unpacks it) on the left hand side.  So, in the example:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

compared to:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

You have different values for `a` when you go to compute `a + b`.  In the second example, when you compute `a + b` it is equivalent to computing `b + b`!

Answer (score 1):

In an assignment statement, the right-hand side is always evaluated fully before doing the actual setting of variables. Because that you get different results

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the flow of data.

```
a = b     ...eqI
b = a+b    ...eqII
```

here, before executing `b` `eqII`, `a` has already stored `b`as a value of itself. Now when yow try execute `b` of `eqII` it comes like `b=b+b`. Because after executing `eqI` when it comes to `eqII`, `a` is `b`now.

But in python you can avoid  this conflict if you try `a, b = b, a+b`.

For your second question:
I am not sure about your code but this one will work fine in the sense of your code...

```
a = b = 1
while True :

a , b = b , a + b

if a and b > 100:
    break
else: print a, b
```

try it !!

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

This line computes `b` and `a+b` before performing any assignment. Strictly speaking, it computes a tuple `(b, a+b)` and then unpacks the elements of the tuple to assign them to `a` and `b`.

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

This assigns `a`, then computes `a+b` using the new value of `a`.

Comment: Actually, *strictly speaking*, no tuple is built.  If you do a inspect the disassembled code (`dis.dis`), you'll notice that there is no `BUILD_TUPLE` bytecode instruction.

Comment: @mgilson: Eh, I meant that more in terms of language semantics than implementation. It's like saying "strictly speaking, calling a function that returns an int through a `void (*)()` is undefined behavior" when really, the particular combination of compiler and settings in use results in the same series of machine instructions as if you'd used an `int (*)()`. Perhaps I should have said "semantically speaking"? It's hard to find a phrase that clearly communicates that I'm talking about what the code says Python should do, rather than the equivalent action the implementation takes.

Comment: @mgilson Its not **always** the case... Please check my answer and the discussion with Martijin [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20582989/1903116)