# Swapping two elements in Python

Tags: python, swap, compare-and-swap

I was watching a video where all of a sudden the instructor uses the given code to swap two elements of a list L:

```
L[suffix], L[i] = L[i], L[suffix]
```

What is the procedure undertaken inside for this method of swap? Is a new list formed? Or a tuple? Or a dictionary? Or something else???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582977/python-swapping-lists

Comment: [This is the answer you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836456/1622937)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to understand

```
>>> L = [0,4]
>>> L[0],L[1] = L[1],L[0]
>>> L
[4, 0]
```

Or this example,in this case you swap first and third element

```
>>> P = [0,4,9]
>>> P[0],P[2] = P[2],P[0]
>>> P
[9, 4, 0]
```

Comment: To what extend does this explain what is happening?